# 'Mouseenter mouseleave' effect is not constant after repeatedly performing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

JSFiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/65gkj96b/1/

I'm trying to input a function that alternates an 'active' and 'inactive' arrow. When the page initially loads, the left arrow is inactive (grey background), and the right arrow is active (hover effect). When the user clicks the right arrow, the left/right arrows are meant to switch so that the left is now active and the right inactive.

Here is my code so far:

```
function moreEmployees() {
  var left = $('#arrow-left');
  var right = $('#arrow-right');

  function activeArrow(active) {
    active.on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
      active.toggleClass('hover-arrow');
    });

    active.removeClass('null-arrow');
  }

  function inactiveArrow(inactive) {
    inactive.addClass('null-arrow');
  }

  inactiveArrow(left);
  activeArrow(right);

  $('.more-workers').hide();
  right.on('click', function() {
    $('.current-workers').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.more-workers').fadeIn(1000);

    inactiveArrow(right);
    activeArrow(left);
  });

  left.on('click', function() {
    $('.more-workers').fadeOut(1000);
    $('.current-workers').fadeIn(1000);

    inactiveArrow(left);
    activeArrow(right);
  });
}

moreEmployees();
```

So, initially the function works, but sometimes the 'mouseenter mouseleave' effect disappears and is not shown for either arrow. Then, it will come back if you keep clicking the arrows. I want the function to work consistently, any help would be appreciated :(

Comment: You are creating duplicate bindings.  Every time you do `on(event, ...)` on an element, it adds a new one.  Previously created ones **are not removed** .  Such is the case with the calls to `activeArrow`

Comment: @Taplar I see. So I would have to use something other than `on(event, ...)` to make this work? Or is there a way to remove a previous binding?

Comment: Instead of binding multiple times, it would be better to bind once, and change the processing to account for the conditions in which it should not do anything, and the cases when it should perform work.

Comment: you can use .unbind() Here is the documentation: 
http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: @totallytypicalcow I tried unbinding the effect when the arrow is inactive, but now the hover effect starts working oppositely after a few clicks (golden background when mouse is not hovering, and no background when mouse is hovering). [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/65gkj96b/4/).

Comment: I think I got it working... https://jsfiddle.net/65gkj96b/60/  
I just separated the mouseenter and mouseleave functions and that seemed to do the trick to fix it from stopping working randomly. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @totallytypicalcow Yeah, omg thank you!!!!!!